# Linq filter List<string> where it contains a string value from another List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, filtering

I have 2 List objects (simplified):

```
var fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseSourceFolderStr, fileNameStartStr + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var filterList = new List<string>();
filterList.Add("ThisFolderName");
filterList.Add("ThatFolderName");
```

I want to filter the fileLst to return only files containing any of folder names from the filterList. (I hope that makes sense..)

I have tried the following expression, but this always returns an empty list.

```
var filteredFileList = fileList.Where(fl => fl.Any(x => filterList.Contains(x.ToString())));
```

I can't seem to make sense of why I am getting nothing, clearly I am missing something, but I have no idea what.

[EDIT]

Ok, so it appears I should have been clearer in my question, I was trying to search for files in my fileList with a substring containing string values from my filterList. I have marked the answer below for those who are trying to do a similar thing.

Comment: Why you used any ? var filteredFileList = fileList.Where(fl => filterList.Contains(fl));

Comment: I think,for your expression, you take a single filelist than x will be a char , it looks if filterList contains the char.(string become IEnumerable<char>)

Comment: @David Tryon - I've not used Intersect before, though running it, I get an empty list when I know it should contain some values: var filteredFileList = fileList.Intersect(filterList);

Comment: @DavutGürbüz - similarly, for your simplified query (I was using .Any as I have done much playing around with different examples..) I am returning no results.  I know my fileList has strings in it that contain those in the filterList. I confess to being a little stumped..

Comment: fileList.Intersect(filteredFileList) as @DavinTryon said is a shortcut.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

its even easier:

```
fileList.Where(item => filterList.Contains(item))
```

in case you want to filter not for an exact match but for a "contains" you can use this expression:

```
var t = fileList.Where(file => filterList.Any(folder => file.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(folder.ToUpperInvariant())));
```

Comment: I thought it should be easy like this too, but for some reason, my filtered list is empty, when I know it *should* contain some string values, could I be missing something somewhere else?

Comment: make sure that the directory names are really equal --> "c:\test" is not equal to "c:\TEST\"

Comment: Don't forget to check for nulls in there.

Comment: Make sure you include a 'using System.Linq' before you wonder why intellisense isn't working. That was my trouble today!

Comment: the same thing i want to achieve but using sql like syntax. Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 10):

Try the following:

```
var filteredFileSet = fileList.Where(item => filterList.Contains(item));
```

When you iterate over **filteredFileSet** (See [LINQ Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)) it will consist of a set of IEnumberable values. This is based on the Where Operator checking to ensure that items within the **fileList** data set are contained within the **filterList** set.

As **fileList** is an [IEnumerable set of string values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx), you can pass the '**item**' value directly into the Contains method.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that

```
var filteredFileList = fileList.Where(fl => filterList.Contains(fl.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from employee
Where cityID in ( select cityID from cities where countryID=1)