# Compare 2 List<string> with a LIKE clause

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have 2 lists, one a list of file names, the second a list of file name stubs, i would like to select everything from the first list where the file name is like the file name stub.

```
List<string> files = new List<string>() {"a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"};
List<string> fileStub = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"};
```

The query would return all records from the first list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**, include attempted solutions

Comment: Ahh, fair enough, I have been tinkering around for a while with this, and a fair bit of Googling, but didn't get the right result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq filter List<string> where it contains a string value from another List<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879771/linq-filter-liststring-where-it-contains-a-string-value-from-another-liststri)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var results = files.Where(x => fileStub.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Comment: You were 2 minutes faster than me :)

Comment: Perfect.  I knew t would be something like that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

if the order is important (of course, with this sample, the size of the two lists is important, if you don't want IndexOutOfRange exceptions)

```
var res = files.Where((file, index) => file.Contains(fileStub[index]));
```

if you don't mind order (than list sizes are not important)

```
var res = files.Where(file => fileStub.Any(fs => file.Contains(fs)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = files.Where(item => fileStub.Any(stub => item.Contains(stub))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) and [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) methods.

```
List<string> files = new List<string>() {"a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"};
List<string> fileStub = new List<string>() {"a", "c"};
var result = files.Where(x => fileStub.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList();
```