# NullReferenceException when querying Ids using LINQ and Contains

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am getting a `NullReferenceException` when trying to run the following query:

```
 var questions = db.questions
                .Where(t => Ids.Contains(t.id));


  foreach (var q in questions) // exception
  {
   var a = q.id;
  }
```

The exception rises in the foreach statement.

In the database I have a `questions` table with one record with an Id = 1.

If I query with `t => t.id == 1` I get results.

The Ids is a `List<long>` type. When running the code, the Ids variable contains one item, which is the value 1.

My goal is to retrieve the questions with id (primary key) that equals to one or more Ids in the `Ids` list.

So for example: if the list contains the numebrs 1,3,5, the query should return the rows from the questions table that match records with the corresponding Ids,which are 1,3 and 5.

Using Entity Framework 6 with MySQL.

Comment: What happens when you call .ToList() after here: .Where(t => Ids.Contains(t.id));, like .Where(t => Ids.Contains(t.id)).ToList();

Comment: Either your `db` or `questions` variable is null. Did you debug your code?

Comment: @GrantWinney When I use toList I still get the same exception. I am debugging the code.

Comment: @GrantWinney I am not ef expert but is it possible to query like that if yes how ef would materialise the query with IDs having in memory collection?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Hi, db is not null as it being initialized and the query works when I use t => t.id == 1.  I assume that questions is null because there is something wrong with the query,

Comment: @GrantWinney I've seen this code in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879771/linq-filter-liststring-where-it-contains-a-string-value-from-another-liststri  so I assume that hsould have worked out.

Comment: @GrantWinney I agree but will it also populate all the element of the collection within in clause of materialized query?

Comment: @Dirk I read it and I didn't find the answer to 'contains' there.

Comment: @IdanShechter try `db.questions.ToList().Where(t => Ids.Contains(t.id))` just for testing. I think then error would disappear.

Comment: @IdanShechter almost all possibilities of a NullReferenceException are listed in that post. Let's see what could possibly be null in your code: db, questions, Ids and t.

Comment: @Jenish Your code works!

Comment: @JenishRabadiya you code db.questions.ToList().Where(t => Ids.Contains(t.id)) worked!  Smart solution. Write an answer and I will accept  it. Thanks

Comment: @IdanShechter I know it would work but it will apply filter after getting records from db instead we should find out some way to filter it in sql itself. Why to fetch all the records when you need only few?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Oh, you are right, didn't think about it.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya this workaround worked for me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/where-in-clause?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: @IdanShechter so did you tried that expression builder solution? You should post answer here if you got solution it may be helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.

```
  static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(
Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
    {
        if (null == valueSelector) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector"); }
        if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }
        ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
        // p => valueSelector(p) == values[0] || valueSelector(p) == ...
        if (!values.Any())
        {
            return e => false;
        }
        var equals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));
        var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
    }
```

And than use:

```
  var questions = db.questions.Where(
                    BuildContainsExpression<question, long>(e => e.id, Ids));
```

The solution I've got from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/where-in-clause?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your Ids

```
 List<long> Ids = new List<long> {1, 3, 5};
```

and this is a sample Question list

```
var questions = new List<Questions>()
                        {
                            new Questions {Id = 1},
                            new Questions {Id = 3},
                            new Questions {Id = 5},
                            new Questions {Id = 4}
                        }
```

this line should work fine.

```
var result = questions.Where(e => Ids.Contains(e.Id)).ToList();
```